# Images disappear when clicked on iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

Ok, weird issue:

1) Go here on an iPhone (Safari browser): http://powellcreative.com/our-team/

2) Click any of the team images to get to the team member page

3) Click the back button on the browser

4) The image is disappeared on the Team page now

Comment: We're having this issue as well with our form submit buttons.  Any progress?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is kind of old, but I was looking for a solution to a similar problem and after searching, I found a solution. Hopefully this helps other people with the same problem.  The problem is when you give iOS a javascript event like onmouseover or onmouseout it doesn't like it, mainly because when your finger is "mousing over" an element in iOS, you are actually clicking on it, so this is the solution I came up with that seems to reload images after hitting the back button in iOS.

Here it is:

Make sure all images are in their own separate div with a distinctive name.
Example:

```
<div name="div1"><a href="dosomething"><img src="yourimage" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='yourimage2';" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='yourimage';"></a></div>
```

In the javascript head part of your page you want to insert this:

```
window.onpageshow = 
function(event){
if (event.persisted){
//for every div and image you want changed back you can add a loop here to change all at once or just one div by name//
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<a href="dosomething"><img src="yourimage" onmouseover="this.src="yourimage2";" onmouseout="this.src="yourimage";"></a>';
}
}
```

This will check for page back since Mobile Safari uses bfcache and reload your image into the div.  Hopefully this helps OP or someone else.